# Prove that $x^2-y^2=666$ has no positive integer solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What I tried:
$$(x+y)(x-y)=2\cdot 3^2\cdot 37$$
and I tried solving for $x$ and $y$ will $x+y=1$ factor and $x-y=$another factor
but I don't like this proof I think there might be a better way of proving this.

Comment: Consider mod 4.

Comment: Well, $x\pm y$ are either both odd or both even ...

Comment: Try setting $a=3x$ and $b=3y$, and see where you go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x+y$ and $x-y$ are integers, then their sum must be an integer; what's more, it must be an even one, as $(x+y)+(x-y)=2x$, which is even for all integer values of $x$. This forces both factors to be of the same parity, but this is impossible: the prime factorization of $666$ includes only one factor of $2$, so no matter how they are grouped, there will be a group with no factor of $2$ and will therefore be odd while the other is even. Therefore their sum cannot be even, which means that $x$ cannot be an integer. The same argument can be used to show that $y$ cannot be an integer either.

This argument extends to any problem of the form $x^2-y^2=c$, where $c$ is a positive integer containing only one factor of $2$.

Comment: same as $36=2^2*3^2$ but also as a triangular number $36=n(n+1)/2=8*9/2$.

Answer (score 2):

We can rearrange this to get $(3x)^2 - (3y)^2 = 2 \times 37$ in virtue of the fact that 666 is a multiple of 9.

We can see that the LHS is a multiple of 3, but there are no factors of 3 on the RHS! The only possibility is that the LHS is $0$, but the RHS is clearly positive, a contradiction.